# Import file with multiple column file as variables with pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a .txt file with several columns from a measurement.
These values came from sensors and the number of columns is **not always the same**.

The file structure looks something like this (it has about 40 lines of "trash" from the descriptions of the sensors, dates and so on):

1,09666671875554    1,01333338146408    1,70666674772898    -8,36548137664795   69,9546508789063    1,09666671875554    1,01333338146408    1,70666674772898

I would like to create a script that is able to know how many columns does each file contain and afterwards import each columns as a variable, e.g., column 1 is named "a", column 2-->"b", column 3 -->"c" and so on.

So far I was able to import all the data into only variable:

```
import pandas as pd

test=pd.read_csv(filename, sep='/s+', lineterminator='\r',skiprows=40,engine='python',index_col=0)
```

The output looks something like this

```
Out[3]: 

Empty DataFrame

Columns: []

Index: [1,10666671923051    1,02333338193906    1,71666674820396    -8,34606075286865   69,9546813964844    1,10666671923051    1,02333338193906
```

I am using anaconda on a windows Pc. Can anyone give me a help with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `header` for default columns names - `0,1,2..` and then `rename` them by `dictionary`:

```
import string
#dict for map columns
d = dict(zip(range(26), list(string.ascii_lowercase)))
print (d)
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 
 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o',
 15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't', 20: 'u', 
 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z'}


test=pd.read_csv(filename, 
                 sep='/s+', 
                 lineterminator='\r',
                 skiprows=40,
                 engine='python',
                 index_col=0,
                 header=None)

test = test.rename(columns=d)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

_df_ is not defined previously.  Is it supposed to be _d_?

Comment: sorry, I think test ;)

Comment: The output is the same as before.

Did it work for you?

Out[9]: 

Empty DataFrame

Columns: []

Index: [1,10333338573885 1,0200000484474 1,7133334147123 -8,35449504852295 69,9546737670898 1,10333338573885 1,0200000484474 1,7133334147123 0,206773042678833, 1,10666671923051 1,02333338193906 1,71666674820396

Comment: Hmmm, if dont want set first column to index remove `index_col=0` from `read_csv`

Comment: The column a appears, but the structure is strange.
Out[11]: 
                                                       a
0      1,10333338573885\t1,0200000484474\t1,713333414...

[15157 rows x 1 columns]
Before removing the line it came with 0 columns and now it has 1 column. I guess there is some improvement, ehhehe

Comment: Or if use `sep='\s+'` ?

Comment: This is how the data structure looks like

[https://imgur.com/a/x8N6c]

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I have idea -can you send me some sample data to my email in my profile? Because it looks like data problem, maybe someting with separators, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok!
I solved this with:

```
import string
#dict for map columns
d = dict(zip(range(26), list(string.ascii_lowercase)))
print (d)
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 
 8: 'i', 9: 'j', 10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o',
 15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't', 20: 'u', 
 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z'}



test=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\s+',skiprows=40,engine='python',names=d, header=None, decimal=',')
test = test.rename(columns=d)

#clear data that is not needed
test.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```